# what is the best server or cloud hosting for my laravel+Vuejs2 application?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, hosting

I Have an application with laravel 5.5 And Vuejs 2 My application  is dedicated for students  so there are many files (pdf...) maybe some tutorials ... and i'd like to find the best server/cloud hosting for that , thank's .

Comment: Answers to this question would be only based on someones opinion

Comment: cloud Hosting  https://www.digitalocean.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Would suggest you to go with AWS.

You can use EC2 for your server side and s3 to direct hosting of vuejs frontend. 
If you have mixed the laravel and vuejs together, then you can use only EC2

Or directly use Elastic beanstalk to setup a AMI with php, apache installed. EB will create EC2 for you automatically and install all your required stack.

You can store your your pdf files/tutorials on s3.

Comment: To add to this - you can then use Laravel Forge to deploy if you're new to the dev ops side of things, which makes getting apps live much less scary.

Comment: Hey thank's for your answer , what about HEROKU what do you think :) ?

Comment: Your can also use heroku. But I suggest AWS, becuase you can do lots of things at single place. you can setup lamda for internal computing and all. Event the kind of flexibility aws is providing is unreachable by any other cloud service provide.

Comment: oky thanks a lot man :)